# Forward incoming mail on Linux server?

Tags: linux, email-server, mail-forwarding

I am trying to set up mail forwarding on a new server of mine. For example, I want emailaddress@mydomain.com to forward all email sent to it to, say, otheremail@gmail.com. I do not need/want to be able to send mail from mydomain.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and it's my server so I have root access and can install/modify anything necessary. I have a few years of Linux experience, but never played with mail servers before so I literally know nothing about them. Hence, I can't really understand all the questions that have been previously asked about this topic. There also seems to be many different answers given and it would take forever to read about every solution proposed. That being said, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I prefer postfix, it's easier to configure and by default, most things are turned off:

1. Install postfix.
2. In /etc/postfix/main.cf set these two options

   ```
   mydomain = example.com
   mydestination = example.com
   ```

   Replace "example.com" with your actual domain. This is **very important**
3. Optionally in main.cf, set `myhostname` to something appropriate (could also be "example.com")
4. Add this line somewhere in main.cf:

   ```
   local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
   ```

   this turns off local transport so email delivery to local users are turned off (you can skip this is you want local users to receive email).
5. In main.cf, make sure you have this line (there should be lots of variations that have been commented out):

   ```
   alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases # (or `hash:/etc/mail/aliases`, etc.)
   ```
6. Now edit the `/etc/aliases` (or `/etc/mail/aliases` or whatever it was in main.cf) and create the alias: `emailaddress: otheremail@gmail.com`, this will make it so incoming email for "emailaddress@example.com" get forwarded to "otheremail@gmail.com"
7. Save main.cf and run this command: `postalias /etc/aliases` (or `/etc/mail/aliases` or whatever it was in main.cf).
8. Start postfix: `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start`

Here is some more info for postfix on ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Comment: Sounds pretty easy as well. I will update once my DNS admin getting the MX record needed.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that you need to point your domain's MX record to this server.

Comment: After failing to get sendmail working correctly, I tried using Postfix with your directions. It's working beautifully now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting ```Recipient address rejected: local delivery is disabled```

Comment: @OliverDixon me too.

Comment: What if there are several domains all pointing at this server via virtual hosts? How should the instructions be modified if `info@mydomain1.com` and `info@mydomain2.com` both need to be forwarded?

Comment: @osullic you'll need to add the additional domains to the mydomains/mydestination lines, examples: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination

Answer (score 4):

Do you already have a functioning incoming mail server?  Have you setup MX records for you domain yet?

- Set up mx records in DNS
- Install sendmail

Set up `/etc/mail/virtusertable` with the following forwarding line:

```
emailaddress@mydomain.com   otheremail@gmail.com
```

Comment: That simple huh? I contacted my DNS admin about adding the MX record and already have sendmail installed. Hopefully the MX record will be added tomorrow and I'll update then.

Comment: I decided to try this method. It wasn't "that simple". But it's pretty straightforward - just a few steps to go through. I posted the steps as an [answer to my own question](https://serverfault.com/a/914930) - which seems to be the same as this one.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice from @jon-lin, and got stuck with mail bouncing back with a Recipient address rejected: local delivery is disabled message. I found that setting up virtual alias maps worked.

1. Install postfix.
2. Add these lines to main.cf:

   `virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com myanotherdomain.com`

   `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`
3. Set up `/etc/postfix/virtual` as follows:

   `contact@mydomain.com myself@gmail.com`

   `sales@mydomain.com myself@gmail.com`

   The first email is the address on which postfix shall receive emails, and the second is the address where postfix would forward the emails. Notice that the format here is different than the alias file - it is space separated.
4. Run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
5. Reload postfix config with `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload`

See this guide for reference: http://www.binarytides.com/postfix-mail-forwarding-debian/